# MYSQL Selection from two tables

Tags: mysql, select

I'm using mysql for my database, I'm fine with, the simple queries are no problem, but now I have to select from two tables and I have no idea how I can do it.

I have two tables, one with suppliers one with articles in it.

Here is my rough schema:

```
supplierdb 
sid,searchname,name,adress 

articlesdb 
aid,quantities,description,price,->sid<-
```

My question is: how do I select in a articles select query the searchname of sid without doing two separate queries?

I want that the query returns:

```
aid,description,price,searchname(from supplierdb)
```

Comment: is there any relation between both tables??

Comment: mate you should just google and research. this is no stackoverflow question

Comment: there are no relation between the tables

Comment: @kommradHomer dont know why you feel offended, im not a professional mysql user, im just trying to learn, anyway thanks

Comment: why would i ever be offended.trying to show you your way through stackoverflow. this is a great site and if youre a programmer you will value this site all your life, so im trying to help you for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY JOIN

```
SELECT aid,description,price,searchname
FROM supplierdb s
INNER JOIN articledb a ON a.sid = s.sid
```

Comment: isnt that twisted? i want aid,description,price from articledb and lsname from supplierdb, im currently looking on inner join in mysql manual

Comment: because there is no common name of both table columns